# How do I add subcommand support with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have this code, and I want to add subcommand support. Currently, using subcommands, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1089, in wrapper
    await self._call(interaction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1221, in _call
    command, options = self._get_app_command_options(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1140, in _get_app_command_options
    raise CommandNotFound(name, parents)
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Application command 'add' not found
```

How can I add subcommand support to my code?

```py
import discord, discord.app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import handlers
import asyncio
import random
import csv
from project_types import unopened_file
import lol
import re

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.reactions = True
intents.members = True

bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(bot)

@tree.command(name="group")
async def group(interaction, subcommand: str): 
    response = "test"
    await interaction.response.send_message(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "subcommand" is a command inside a "command Group", which you can create like so:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
tree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(client)

command_group = discord.app_commands.Group(name="group", description="Some related commands.")
tree.add_command(command_group)

@command_group.command()
async def a(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
  await interaction.response.send_message("Invoked command group > a")

@command_group.command()
async def b(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
  await interaction.response.send_message("Invoked command group > b")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

This will create two commands: `/group a` and `/group b`. Remember to [synchronize the command tree](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.sync).

Comment: I get the `TypeError: groups must have a description`.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1089, in wrapper
    await self._call(interaction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1221, in _call
    command, options = self._get_app_command_options(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1125, in _get_app_command_options
    raise CommandNotFound(name, parents)
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Application command 'group' not found`

Comment: Adding the description, I get this error when running the slash command

Comment: Never mind, I had forgotten to add it to the tree.